# R: Filter vectors by 'two-way' partial match

Tags: r

With two vectors

```
x <- c("abc", "12")
y <- c("bc", "123", "nomatch")
```

is there a way to do a filter of both by 'two-way' partial matching (remove elements in one vector if they contain or are contained in any element in the other vector) so that the result are these two vectors:

```
x1 <- c()
y1 <- c("nomatch")
```

To explain - every element of x is either a substring or a superstring of one of the elements of y, hence x1 is empty.  Update - it is not sufficient for a substring to match the initial chars - a substring might be found anywhere in the string it matches.  Example above has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: How much partial matching do you want to do? for `abc`, does `a` match? Does `abcd` match? Does `cab` match?

Comment: If "a" is an element, then it matches with any string containing "a" as it is a substring of them.  However, if "ab" is an element, then it doesn't match "ac" because neither is a substring or superstring of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought `?pmatch` might be handy, but your edit clarifies you don't just want to match the start of items. Here's a function that should work:

```
remover <- function(x,y) {
    pmx <- sapply(x, grep, x=y)
    pmy <- sapply(y, grep, x=x)

    hit <- unlist(c(pmx,pmy))

    list(
        x[!(seq_along(x) %in% hit)],
        y[!(seq_along(y) %in% hit)]
    )
}

remover(x,y)
#[[1]]
#character(0)
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "nomatch"
```

It correctly does nothing when no match is found (thanks @Frank for picking up the earlier error):

```
remover("yo","nomatch")
#[[1]]
#[1] "yo"
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] "nomatch"
```

Comment: This seems to only work if the substring matches the initial chars.  For example, it should also match "bc" with "abc".  I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: @Vlad "Partial matching" means matching the initial chars, fyi. Btw, generally bad form to edit the question in a way that invalidates an answer...

Comment: @Frank - I think I've sorted it now, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Frank - please could you provide a reference to 'partial matching' matching initial characters.

Comment: @Vlad Eg `?charmatch` says "partial matches (those where the value to be matched has an exact match to the initial part of the target, but the target is longer)." This terminology might be unique to R... my knowledge of regex/string parsing is not very broad.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the following:

```
# Return data.frame of matches of a in b
m <- function(a, b) {
    data.frame(sapply(a, function(w) grepl(w, b), simplify = F));
}

# Match x and y and remove
x0 <- x[!apply(m(x, y), 2, any)]
y0 <- y[!apply(m(x, y), 1, any)]

# Match y and x and remove
x1 <- x0[!apply(m(y0, x0), 1, any)]
y1 <- y0[!apply(m(y0, x0), 2, any)]

x1;
#character(0)

x2;
#[1] "nomatch"
```

Answer (score 1):

I build a matrix of all possible matches in both directions, then combine both with `|` as a match in any direction is equally a match, and then and use it to subset `x` and `y`:

```
x <- c("abc", "12")
y <- c("bc", "123", "nomatch")

bool_mat <- sapply(x,function(z) grepl(z,y)) | t(sapply(y,function(z) grepl(z,x)))
x1 <- x[!apply(bool_mat,2,any)] # character(0)
y1 <- y[!apply(bool_mat,1,any)] # [1] "nomatch"
```